# How to avoid file selection with "Refresh all" in Excel from Python

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to have an Excel file, which I already have setup, to have its connection (only one present) refreshed via Python and then it should open the updated file. The code below is to use the RefreshAll function in Excel

```
# Start an instance of Excel
xlapp = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")

# Open the workbook in said instance of Excel
wb = xlapp.workbooks.open(r"C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\Python test\Prova.xlsx")

# Refresh all data connections.
wb.RefreshAll()
```

But it asks me which file should it use to update the connection via a popup window. Now, the file will always be the same. How can I implement a silent update?
Also, how can I have it open up the spreadsheet when the update is complete?

Thanks

Comment: Still waiting for help.

Comment: This is still an issue for me.